# Why doesn't this BinaryReader in JavaScript work similarly to the C# BinaryReader?

Tags: javascript

I found [this JavaScript library](http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-binary-reader.html) and I wanted to use it. I wanted to make a small web page that uses a `.bin` file to get it's info. I've already done it in C#. It was hard finding this JavaScript file. I don't know why this doesn't work. It's supposed to fill some empty options with text it finds in the `bin` file.

```js
function ReadTableContents(beginTable, endTable, s) {
    var binread = new BinaryReader(load_binary_resource('mh3_80.BIN'));
    var t = 0;
    beginTable &= 0x0FFFFFFF;
    endTable &= 0x0FFFFFFF;
    while (beginTable <= endTable) {
        if (binread.getPosition() >= binread.getSize()) break;
        binread.seek(beginTable);
        var pointerHere = binread.readUInt32();
        binread.seek(pointerHere);
        var txtTable = '';
        var c = binread.readChar();
        while (c != '\0') {
            txtTable += c;
            c = binread.readChar();
        }
        document.getElementById('opt' + s + t).innerHTML = txtTable.Replace("\'", "\\\'").Replace("ããã¼", "???").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
        beginTable += 0x4;
        t++;
    }
}
```

This is what I wrote in C# to create some javascript code for me.

```cs
public static void ReadTableContents(BinaryReader binread, string outtxt, UInt32 beginTable, UInt32 endTable, int z)
{
    string arrayout = Path.GetDirectoryName("DUMP80.BIN");
    arrayout = Path.Combine(arrayout, outtxt);
    TextWriter arraywrite = new StreamWriter(arrayout, true);
    arraywrite.WriteLine("if (document.getElementById('slctType').value == "+ z + "){");
    int t = 0;
    beginTable &= 0x0FFFFFFF;
    endTable &= 0x0FFFFFFF;
    while (beginTable <= endTable)
    {
        if (binread.BaseStream.Position >= binread.BaseStream.Length) break;
        binread.BaseStream.Seek(beginTable, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        UInt32 pointerHere = Swap(binread.ReadUInt32());
        string txtTable = getDumpString(binread, pointerHere);
        arraywrite.WriteLine("document.getElementById('optEquip" + t + "').innerHTML = '" + txtTable.Replace("\'", "\\\'").Replace("ããã¼", "???").Replace("\"", "\\\"") +"';");
        beginTable += 0x4;
        t++;
    }
    arraywrite.WriteLine("}");
    arraywrite.WriteLine();
    arraywrite.Flush();
    arraywrite.Close();
    return;
}
```

It's the same thing, really; just one is JavaScript that'll do the option modding, and the other one makes some JavaScript for me to copy and paste. But that's bootleg. So here's what ends up happening:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24514984/modcodes.htm

I only coded the stuff for if you pick weapons->Greatsword. But if you pick Greatsword, an empty dropdown box appears. What's wrong with my JavaScript function?

Comment: Solved. It was a silly mistake. When I was modifying the C# code into js, I forgot to Change Replace() to replace(). The code works fine now. I can't believe I took so long to notice that. replace() is kind of useless for this though, because it doesn't replace the unknown characters with ???? like I wanted. Oh well. I also decided to use jDataView instead of BinaryReader because it's "new".